# Optibay drive ejects after 10 minutes

Tags: external-hard-drive, macbook-pro, optical-drive

I have replaced my optical drive in Macbook Pro mid 2012 with Optibay disk - Hitachi Travelstar 5K1000 1TB internal harddrive (6,4 cm (2,5 inch), 5400rpm, SATA III). I have formatted it to Mac OS Extended (Journaled). When I try to copy few big files - approximately after 10 min of copying I get this error message

[image]

and the drive disappears from disk utility and is only visible in the System Information menu as unknown. It appears again only if I do the safe boot and then again boot normally.
Could you please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I've added the image inline for you. For some reason your host didn't let me simply supply the url to the image, so i ended up needing to download and upload it. Using Imgur even when you lack the rep to use the built in image linking function makes things a little easier for someone editing your question

Answer (score -1):

Those Macbooks have that problem when using SATAIII 6Gb/s, downgrade your harddrive to SATAII 3Gb/s

http://www.mcetech.com/optibay/sata3to2.html